# set form that opens with project in delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-2010

I have a particular delphi project which no longer opens any forms in the ide when I open the project file (either .dpr or .dproj). I still see all my forms in the project manager, and can open them from there, but I have become accustomed to the main form in the project opening along with the project.

Is there a simple setting I can change in the project file or in the ide to get this behavior back?

Comment: Tools|Options|Environment Options|Autosave Options|Project desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `Project desktop` property in `Tools|Options|Environment Options|Autosave Options`.